# My dispatch function works but is not updating redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I understand that this question has been asked several times but my example doesn't suffer from any of the solutions provided in the other examples. I hope someone can help, thanks in advance.

Here's my slice, screenSlice.js:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

//this slice sets the state of the screens Y axis
export const screenSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'screenYPlacement',
  initialState: {
    offsetY: 0,
  },
  reducers: {
    setoffsetY: (state, action) => {
      return {
        ...state,
        offsetY : action.payload
      }
    }
  }
});

export const { setoffsetY } = screenSlice.actions
export default screenSlice.reducer
```

My store, store.js :

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import screenReducer from './screenSlice';

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    offsetY: screenReducer
  },
});
```

The file in which it is called, app.js:

```
import React, { useEffect} from 'react'

import './App.scss';

import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { setoffsetY } from './redux/screenSlice';

import Header from './components/header/Header';
import Hero from './components/hero/Hero';

function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  //this function will use the redux reducer to save the Y axis to redux
  const handleScroll = () => dispatch(setoffsetY(window.pageYOffset));
  
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header/>
      <Hero/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: did you put `<Provider>` around in **index.js**?

Comment: @nosnart Yes here's my index.js file :```import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './redux/store';


ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
    </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);```

Comment: I tried with your code it works as exptected [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ecnfop?file=src/App.js)

Comment: I see, my mistake isn't shown but I think I was trying to still update state in the app file using useState and the dispatch setoffsetY as the set state function. Thank you for your time.